# How to convert json data from alamofire to swift objects

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

> hi there im making a photo viewer app in swift using swift 1.1 in
>   xcode 6.2
>
> i am a having trouble trying to convert json response from
>   alamofire to swift objects.i have used swiftyjson library but it seems
>   there is a compatibility issues.here is my model class

```
import Foundation

struct Photo {

    var name: String
    var filename :String
    var notes: String
}
```

> here is my viewController

```
    import UIKit

    class ImageViewerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var photos = [Photo]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
         .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in

         }

      }
```

how can i map json to swift objects in this situation

thanks .

Comment: What is returned as JSON in Alamofire? If its a class look at its source and try figure out a way to put every single value manually inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use [`AlamofireObjectMapper`](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper).

Your code should look like this:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

struct Photo: Mappable {
    var name: String
    var filename :String
    var notes: String

    required init?(map: Map) {}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.name     <- map["name"]
        self.filename <- map["filename"]
        self. notes   <- map["notes"]
    }
}
```

In viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var photos = [Photo]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire
            .request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
            .responseArray { (response: Response<[Photo], NSError>) in
            if let myPhotos = response.result.value {
                print(myPhotos)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Look the documentation of `AlamofireObjectMapper` and `ObjectMapper` for more informations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dataUsingEncoding` method, and get your `name,filename`and`notes` variables from `json` object, and for parsing json object i recommend [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: nil, encoding: .URL).responseString(completionHandler: {
        (request: NSURLRequest, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, responseBody: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // Convert the response to NSData to handle with SwiftyJSON
        if let data = (responseBody as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            println(json)
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) for that. You can use code like:

```
var photo:Photo = Photo(json:jsonString)
```

or

```
var jsonString:String = photo.toJsonString()
```

You only have to set your base object to EVObject.

See the GitHub page for more detailed sample code (including array's).

Comment: I now also have an Alamofire extension for this. See https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write the mapping function, I recommend you to take a look at [`HandyJSON`](https://github.com/alibaba/handyjson). A code example:

```
struct Animal: HandyJSON {
    var name: String?
    var id: String?
    var num: Int?
}

let jsonString = "{\"name\":\"cat\",\"id\":\"12345\",\"num\":180}"

if let animal = JSONDeserializer.deserializeFrom(json: jsonString) {
    print(animal)
}
```

As it says:

> The most significant feature of HandyJSON is that it does not require the objects inherit from NSObject(not using KVC but reflection), neither implements a 'mapping' function(use pointer to achieve property assignment).